# App crashes on saving data in keychain

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I am using **KeychainItemWrapper** class for saving data in keychain, but my app is crashing with crash log **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'**

Here is a method to write data in keychain

```
- (void)writeToKeychain
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = NULL;
    NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = NULL;
    OSStatus result;

    if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
    {
        // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
        updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
        // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
        [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

        // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
        NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
       [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
        // 
        // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
        // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
        // on the simulator.
        //
        // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
        // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
        //
        // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
        // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

        // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.

        result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
    }
    else
    {
        // No previous item found; add the new one.
        result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);

        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
     }
}
```

**My app is crashing at**

```
result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);
```

with assertion error message **Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain]**

Here is the values assigned in keychainItemData

```
Printing description of self->keychainItemData:
{
    acct = "";
    desc = "";
    gena = "com.xyz.abc";
    labl = "";
    "v_Data" = "ABCDSS-ABCDSS-ABCDSS-TEST-DATA";
}
```

I know the similar questions has been asked here many time but nothing help for me.

Can anyone help me out ? Is there any other approach to save data in keychain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem as you but it happened only in simulator. If you use a real device, probably there will be no any crash occurs. But why is happening on simulator?

Answer (score -1):

Using self.keychainItemData instead of keychainItemData in your method ?

```
- (void)writeToKeychain
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = NULL;
    NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = NULL;
    OSStatus result;

    if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
    {
        // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
        updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
        // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
        [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

        // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
        NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:self.keychainItemData];
       [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
        // 
        // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
        // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
        // on the simulator.
        //
        // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
        // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
        //
        // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
        // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

        // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.

        result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
    }
    else
    {
        // No previous item found; add the new one.
        result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:self.keychainItemData], NULL);

        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
     }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting ? Looking at this code, keychainItemData is just nil.